# Comparing multiple columns difficulty VBA Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to check if column A row 1 matches column B row 1 and if this matches then a check on Column E row 1 with Column E row 2 needs to be conducted. If all match then a value in column C row 1 needs to be displayed.

If column A row 1 matches column B row 1 and if column E row 1 matches column 2 row 2 then move to row 2 and check if column A row 2 matches column A row 2 if this matches check to see if column E row 1 matches column E row 2. if this matches but below line does not match then sum the two values in column C for row 1 and row 2.

I have this piece of code:

```
Sub DemoNew()
    Dim dict1 As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant, k As Variant
    Dim currWS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Double, lastRow As Double, tot As Double
    Dim number1 As Double, number2 As Double, firstRow As Double

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'get last row withh data in Column A
    lastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'put unique numbers in Column A in dict1
    c1 = Range("A2:B" & lastRow)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
        If c1(i, 1) <> "" Then
            'make combination with first 4 characters
            dict1(Left(c1(i, 1), 4) & "," & Left(c1(i, 2), 4)) = 1
        End If
    Next i

    'loop through all the numbers in column A
    For Each k In dict1.keys
        number1 = Split(k, ",")(0)
        number2 = Split(k, ",")(1)
        tot = 0
        firstRow = 0

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If k = Left(currWS.Range("A" & i).Value, 4) & "," & Left(currWS.Range("B" & i).Value, 4) Then
                If firstRow = 0 Then
                    firstRow = i
                End If
                tot = tot + currWS.Range("C" & i).Value
            End If
        Next i
        currWS.Range("D" & firstRow) = tot
    Next k
End Sub
```

I have tried this:

```
If k = Left(currWS.Range("A" & i).Value, 4) & "," & Left(currWS.Range("B" & i).Value, 4) & (currWS.Range("E" & i).value) Then
```

but this does not produce what I wanted.

Here is a graphical representation:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncc4g.png)

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What is happening, cant see the attachment at work

Comment: Please edit this line `if column A row 2 matches column A row 2`.  `C row 1 needs to be displayed` what does be displayed mean? Displayed where?   `then sum the two values in column C for row 1 and row 2` what so you do with the sum? Display it instead of C1?

Comment: I know that you are trying to explain it in as much detail as possible but some pseudo code would more readable. Here is my break down: `If A1 = B1 AND E1 = E2 Then Display E1 = E2 
 
If  A1 = B1 AND E1 = B2 row then 
 If A2 = A2 AND E1 = E2 then 
   C1 + C2
  End If
End IF`

Comment: Ok: If A1 = B1 and E1=E2 then store C1 else D1 = C1 and this needs to keep iteratating like on the excel diagram through all the numbers so if A1 =B1 and E1=E2 then move to next line and see if next line matches if it does keep iterating until they do not match but in process sum the values in column c and store the sum of all the values in column D

Comment: Finding it hard to explain hope you guys know what I am trying to say

Comment: "If A1 = B1 and E1=E2 then store C1" ... Store C1 where? Do you want an array of C1s or are you just increasing "tot" by the value of C1?

Comment: What I want to do is to compare A and B in all columns, if A1 and B1 are 1234 and 1234 and A2 and B2 match with 1234 and 1234 then they should have the same associated date by default so a check on this does not need to be done but a group by date would be useful on the first line of the match.

Answer (score 0):

This do what you need?

```
Sub DemoNew()
    Dim dict1 As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant, k As Variant
    Dim currWS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Double, lastRow As Double, tot As Double
    Dim number1 As Double, number2 As Double, firstRow As Double

    Dim DataArray

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'get last row withh data in Column A
    lastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'put your sheet into an array in memory so that it references faster
    DataArray = Range("A2:E" & lastRow)

    'loop through the array per your logic
    For i = 1 To UBound(DataArray, 1) - 1
        If DataArray(i, 1) <> "" And DataArray(i, 1) = DataArray(i, 2) And DataArray(i, 5) = DataArray(i + 1, 5) Then
           tot = tot + DataArray(i, 3)
        Else
           DataArray(i, 4) = DataArray(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
    DataArray(UBound(DataArray, 1), 4) = DataArray(UBound(DataArray, 1), 3) ' last row will never match the next so set the value in D

    'write modified data back into sheet
    currWS.Range("A2:E" & lastRow) = DataArray

    MsgBox ("Tot is: " & tot)

End Sub
```